# Does Googlebot support TLS v1.2? If not, what will my TLS v1.2-only site look like to it?

Tags: seo, search-engines, https, googlebot, bingbot

I currently redirect all non-HTTPS connections to HTTPS, and support TLS v1, TLS v1.1, and TLS v1.2. I reconfigured my testing server to accept only a very limited and secure cipher suite and TLSv1.2 only. Upon running the [SSL Labs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) I noticed that their compatibility chart showed Bing's and Google's crawlers as not supporting beyond TLSv1.

Is this still accurate? I have not been able to find mention of the bots' protocol support anywhere except on the [SSL Labs results page](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Googlebot&version=Oct%202013).

**Does Googlebot really only support TLS v1?**

If I support only TLS v1.2 and Googlebot is unable to connect to my site, what status will Google consider it to be in?

Comment: I think you should take this question to the google webmaster forum. https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/webmasters

Comment: You should be able to test this yourself using the 'Fetch' within GWT no?

Comment: I was unaware of 'Fetch' as I so very rarely enter GWT. I will  investigate that method post-haste.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: As of Jan 30, 2015, Googlebot supports TLS 1.2 .  See [Post by Google](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GoogleWebmasters/posts/WqzkWWunziN):

> Googlebot now supports TLS version 1.2, in addition to previous
>   versions: TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and SSLv3.

As of September 14th, 2014, the Googlebot does NOT support TLS 1.2. You get notified about 100% inaccessibility and thats it. I am affected by this directly. Using TLS 1.2 SSL enforcement to get on my page.

Here is the proof that Google doesn't like to crawl TLS 1.2 pages as of now:

[image: Google TLS 1.2]

Comment: Please could you edit your question and include a link to the source backing this information up for future visitors.

Comment: @bybe I tried to edit in a link but it wasn't accepted. Source: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Googlebot&version=Jun%202014

Answer (score 2):

Google should be able to handle all versions of SSL/TLS.

The best way to see how Google handles something is via [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home).

*Note: You have to have your site setup in Webmaster Tools for this to work. It's something you should consider anyway.*

1. Go to Webmaster Tools
2. Select your site
3. Select Crawl
4. Select Fetch as Google

Answer (score 1):

Google's crawl bots do not support TLSv1.2, this is fairly well known and people have ranted about Google's failure to support >TLSv1 for a while now as people have tried to make their website get a 100% score on places like SSLlabs -- which means they then get dropped off Google for unreachability.

TLSv1.2 is substantially different from TLSv1. This is a protocol name, not a software version. Any change in the number, even the dotX component, is a significant deviation. Protocols must not change, if they do, they must get a version change.

Answer (score -1):

**Please note:** The version system of TLS like other products means the 1.X.X is Version 1. The 1.**2** is usually reserved for updates, features, maintenance of the Version 1.

I would imagine that Google does have it supported, because they are pretty good at keeping up with the newest standards of security. What I can give proof of is all of the major browsers already support TLS 1.2

- **Chrome** - v30 supports TLS 1.2. Previous to this only up to TLS 1.1 was supported
- **Firefox** - v27 [enables TLS 1.1 and 1.2 by default](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/27.0/releasenotes/)
- **Internet Explorer** - v11 supports TLS 1.2 from Feb 2013
- **Opera** - v17 has added support for TLS 1.2. Versions 10-12 supported TLS 1.1 and 1.2 but disabled it by default, and versions 14-16 supported TLS 1.1 but not 1.2.
- **Safari** - v5 on iOS and v7 on OS X have added support for up to TLS 1.2.

I am going to say yes that Google Bot does support it just like Google Chrome does. I also do say if the browsers are supporting it, I say it is only a few lines of code changed for Google Bot to do support TLS 1.2 also.